# Calling clapack from Cython

Tags: numpy, cython, lapack

I've written the following code to call the clapack routine dgelsy_ from Cython, but it does not give the correct solution to the least squares problem.

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
ctypedef np.float64_t NP_FLOAT_t
ctypedef np.int_t NP_INT_t
ctypedef np.uint8_t NP_BOOL_t    
ctypedef int integer

cdef extern from "clapack.h":
    integer dgelsy_(integer *m, integer *n, integer *nrhs, 
    double *a, integer *lda, double *b, integer *ldb, integer *
    jpvt, double *rcond, integer *rank, double *work, integer *
    lwork, integer *info)

cpdef dgelsy(np.ndarray[NP_FLOAT_t,ndim=2] A, np.ndarray[NP_FLOAT_t,ndim=1] b, np.ndarray[NP_INT_t,ndim=1] jpvt):
    cdef integer m = A.shape[0]
    cdef integer n = A.shape[1]
    cdef integer nrhs = 1
    cdef integer lda = m
    cdef integer ldb = m
    cdef integer rank
    cdef NP_FLOAT_t rcond = 1e-16
    cdef integer lwork = -1
    cdef integer info

    #First call as a workspace query
    cdef np.ndarray[NP_FLOAT_t, ndim=1] work1 = np.empty(shape=1,dtype=np.float)
    dgelsy_(&m, &n, &nrhs, <double*>A.data, &lda, <double*>b.data, &ldb, 
            <integer*>jpvt.data, &rcond, &rank, <double*>work1.data, &lwork, &info)

    #Now the actual call to solve the problem
    lwork = <integer>work1[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[NP_FLOAT_t, ndim=1] work2 = np.empty(shape=lwork,dtype=np.float)
    dgelsy_(&m, &n, &nrhs, <double*>A.data, &lda, <double*>b.data, &ldb, 
            <integer*>jpvt.data, &rcond, &rank, <double*>work2.data, &lwork, &info)
    return rank, info
```

I believe my setup.py file is correct.  My code compiles, links, and runs, but I get compile time warnings and the solution I get is not correct.  Here is my Python test code:

```
import numpy
import cylapack #cylapack is my cython module with the code above
numpy.random.seed(1)
A = numpy.random.normal(size=(100,10))
A_ = A.copy()
x = numpy.random.normal(size=10)
b = numpy.dot(A,x) + numpy.random.normal(size=100)
b_ = b.copy()
pivots = numpy.zeros(shape=10,dtype=numpy.int)

print cylapack.dgelsy(A,b,pivots)
print pivots
x_ = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A_,b_,1e-16)[0]
print numpy.sum((numpy.dot(A_,x_) - b_)**2)
print numpy.sum((numpy.dot(A_,b[0:10]) - b_)**2)
```

which outputs the following:

```
(10, 0)
[25769803780 12884901896 30064771077 38654705666  4294967306           0
           0           0           0           0]
99.8269537854
1087.62032064
```

The last two numbers are the residual sum of squares for the numpy and lapack solutions, respectively.  They should both be the same, but clearly the lapack solution is not actually correct.  Here are my compiler warnings:

```
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 1 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 2 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 3 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 5 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 7 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 8 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 10 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 12 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1424: warning: passing argument 13 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 1 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 2 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 3 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 5 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 7 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 8 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 10 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 12 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
cylapack.c:1495: warning: passing argument 13 of 'dgelsy_' from incompatible pointer type
```

Clearly the compiler is complaining about all my integer pointers (I tried using long instead with no change).  I suspect there is something basic I'm not understanding.  Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It was not my intention to answer my own question, but I've now figured it out.  The problem is that lapack expects matrices in Fortran style column-major order, but numpy uses C style row-major order by default.  If in my test code I change this line:

```
A = numpy.random.normal(size=(100,10))
```

to this:

```
A = numpy.random.normal(size=(10,100)).transpose()
```

then it works fine.  I still don't understand the compiler warnings, though, or the values in pivot, but they seem to be unrelated to the correct solution of the problem.

Comment: might want to use np.intp for the pivots (or equivalent), what I mean is, int (np.int is not int though), is not the correct integer type to pass into your lapack probably.

Comment: Instead of `.transpose()` I'd recommend using `np.asfortranarray(..., dtype='d')` which will ensure that the array is in Fortan order and the data type is double precision.

Comment: Yeah, actually... I would just recommend setting lda/ldb correctly. It does support C order probably if you set things up right.

Comment: @seberg You are correct.  It turns out np.int32_t is the type that matches what lapack is expecting.  When I use that type (and create an np.int32 array), my warnings disappear and my pivots make sense.  With regard to setting lda and ldb for C order, I don't see how that would work. What would be the correct settings for C order?

Comment: Right, I guess it is probably not possible. the dot function has some extra arguments to do such things, so I thought it might work here too.